# I get a error message when using request.get() error on a mac

Tags: python, json, macos, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm a Mac user and I'm trying to use the requests module get() here:

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=star+wars&r=json'
response = requests.get(url)
dic = response.json()
for key in dic:
    print key, ':', dic[key]
```

But I get this:

```
import requests
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/compat.py", line 33, in <module>
    import json
  File "/Users/miguel/Desktop/json.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I've reinstalled the requests library using pip module but it doesn't fix.
Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `requests.urlopen()`?

Comment: @Arman `requests.get()` is valid normally. The OP has named the script `json.py` and it's messing up the imports.

Answer (score 0):

You've named your own script `json.py` which we can see in the last line of the traceback:

`File "/Users/miguel/Desktop/json.py", line 4, in <module>`

Don't do that, you're now masking the actual `json` module and that's going to do some damage to `requests`'s ability to function. Equally, don't call a script `requests.py`. Just rename the file and it should fix the issue.